# SMS based OTP in keycloak is possible?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am exploring keycloak and I want to build an application that was based on user mobile number, SMS OTP should go to the user for authentication. I am not finding any where.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible through extending Authentication mechanism, check [Authentication SPI documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi)

Take a look at existing solution: https://github.com/nickpack/keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns Even if it doesn't suite your needs you can take the source code as a reference point.

Comment: I tried this solution, but keycloak server doest start:   

`Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1493)
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1526)
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1524)
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:507)
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:485)`

Comment: Where I can find the file `target/keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns-*.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check code given in below link.
https://github.com/9228883664/keycloak-otp-password-authenticator

You can use keycloak for OTP validation as primary login. Many portal want either user can login with username/password or can do login by entering registered mobile number and enter received OTP on portal to login. Valid token needs to be generated by calling keycloak API. This plugin serve the purpose of both user can login with either password or OTP. OOTB keycloak does not provide this feature, instead it provide 2F OTP authenticator with well-known OTP application.