# How to integrate keycloak sms authentication by API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have a keycloak server and Laravel application using custom KeycloakProvider:

```
public function loginByEmail(string $email, string $password): SsoTokens
{
    try {
        $data = $this->realmEndpoint->makeRequest(
            HttpClientProvider::METHOD_POST,
            self::KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL,
            [
                'client_id' => config('services.keycloak.realm_client'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.keycloak.realm_secret'),
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'username' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
                'scope' => 'openid'
            ]
        );
    } catch (TransportUnauthorizedException $e) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException($e);
    } catch (HttpClientException $e) {
        throw new TransportException($e);
    }

    return $this->extractTokens($data);
}
```

Now my goal is to set up basic SMS authentication by the user's mobile phone number. I found some tools ([1](https://github.com/UKGovernmentBEIS/keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns), [2](https://github.com/gwallet/keycloak-sms-authenticator)), but they don't provide API, just HTML pages.
Is there a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMS based OTP in keycloak is possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674676/sms-based-otp-in-keycloak-is-possible)

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam thank you, but it doesn't. I pointed to nickpack's package in my question, it doesn't implement an API to interact with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
To login without knowing someone's password:

1. Send SMS;
2. Confirm phone number by a code;
3. Get the keycloak ID of a target user;
4. Log in as a user having the right to [impersonate](https://blog.softwaremill.com/who-am-i-keycloak-impersonation-api-bfe7acaf051a);
5. Exchange tokens with a target user.

`TOKEN_EXCHANGE` keycloak feature required.

Steps 1-3 I implemented with Laravel, steps 4-5 with Keycloak APIs:

```
public function loginByUserId(string $userId): SsoTokens
    {
        try {
            $impersonatorData = $this->realmEndpoint->makeRequest(
                HttpClientProvider::METHOD_POST,
                self::KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL,
                [
                    'client_id' => config('services.keycloak.realm_client'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.keycloak.realm_secret'),
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'username' => config('services.keycloak.admin_username'),
                    'password' => config('services.keycloak.admin_password'),
                    'scope' => 'openid',
                ]
            );

            $data = $this->realmEndpoint->makeRequest(
                HttpClientProvider::METHOD_POST,
                self::KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL,
                [
                    'client_id' => config('services.keycloak.realm_client'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.keycloak.realm_secret'),
                    'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange',
                    'requested_subject' => $userId,
                    'subject_token' => $impersonatorData['access_token'],
                    'scope' => 'openid',
                ]
            );
        } catch (TransportUnauthorizedException $e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException($e);
        } catch (HttpClientException $e) {
            throw new TransportException($e);
        }

        return $this->extractTokens($data);
    }
```